# Python `with` statement semantic equivalent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am confused why `hit_except` is necessary in the following code from the Python docs [8.5. The with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

> The following code:
>
> ```py
> with EXPRESSION as TARGET:
>     SUITE
> ```
>
> is semantically equivalent to:
>
> ```py
> manager = (EXPRESSION)
> enter = type(manager).__enter__
> exit = type(manager).__exit__
> value = enter(manager)
> hit_except = False
>
> try:
>     TARGET = value
>     SUITE
> except:
>     hit_except = True
>     if not exit(manager, *sys.exc_info()):
>         raise
> finally:
>     if not hit_except:
>         exit(manager, None, None, None)
> ```

Isn't that written more simply like this, or is there a difference I am missing?

```py
manager = (EXPRESSION)
enter = type(manager).__enter__
exit = type(manager).__exit__
value = enter(manager)

try:
    TARGET = value
    SUITE
except:
    if not exit(manager, *sys.exc_info()):
        raise
else:
    exit(manager, None, None, None)
```

Comment: No because then you aren't using `finally`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`finally` guards *any* action that "exits" the current `try` scope.

If there's an action that skips the rest of the code, like `return` and `exit()`, or `continue` / `break` (in a loop), the `else` part will be skipped. In all these cases, the `finally` clause will still fire.

One example of *forcibly* skipping both `finally` and the `__exit__` part of a context manager is `os._exit()`, which is possibly an overkill in most cases.